# how to display default icons when sorting in datatables bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using datatables in bootstrap, but the default icons in the chart just don't display, 
there's the example on [datatables official website](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

what I want to display are the default icons as follows:

desc:[image: desc]
asc:[image]

the chart should be like this:
[image]

but it actually shows like this:[image]

I used PHP to insert links of datables javascript and css, is there and mistake in my self-defined css or javascript function that lead to this problem?

```js
$('#table-sort').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        info: false,
        "order":[[2,"desc"]],
        "columnDefs":[{
            "orderable":false,
            "targets":[0,1]
        }]
    });
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered compact table-sorting dataTable" id="table-sort" cellspacing="0" role="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th id="closing_date" style="cursor: pointer">deadline</th>
            <th id="update_date" style="cursor: pointer">update</th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

Thanks to all of you for having read my question patiently and I'd be appreciate if anyone offers any solution .

Comment: pls check your console any error display ?

Comment: I'm sorry I checked the console but it shows no error .

Comment: why some option only double quotes ?, check it

Comment: I unable check your coding, put your coding in jsfiddle or others

Comment: thank u , I just find out that it's the method I added the css went wrong! I should have linked the stylesheet by a <link> tag rather than using PHP! which made the browser load jquery.css before the stylesheet of bootstrap! anyway thank you for your time to help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feel sorry to find out it's the method I load the stylesheet that lead to this problem,
I should use `<link>` tag to load the jquery stylesheet rather than PHP

---

the way I load the files before were as follows

`<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/common/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css", CClientScript::POS_HEAD);?>`

after I changed the load method it works fine

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo zmf::config('baseurl');?>/common/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">`